# Django update model field based on other model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='a_b')
    some_boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I want to set `A.count` for all `A` objects in the following way:

```
A.count = (Number of B's for A with some_boolean=True) * 10
         + Number of B's for A with some_boolean=False
```

I tried the following:

```
all = A.objects.prefetch_related('bs').all()
for a in all:
    # Modify object
    # Save object
```

But this is very inefficient. Any suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: Should `count` always reflect a value computed like this when accessed, or do you want to assign and persist it at one point in time and not change when the associated `B` objects change?

Comment: By No of i mean count of B's.

Comment: So i am adding a new field 'count' in A. So i am doing this for the data migration. Any changes post the migration are already handled. @das-g

Comment: I'm just wondering whether `count` could be a computed property instead of a field. If I get you right, it **must** be a field and the formula given here is just for the initial value used in the migration?

Comment: By the way, if this only happens in the migration, it won't be called all the time. So in what regard do you think your approach is (too?) inefficient?

Comment: Because i have about 10 million A objects and each A object has upto 100 B objects. So it will take a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670519/dgango-update-model-field-based-on-other-model?noredirect=1#comment59020802_35670519) you say you

> have about 10 million `A` objects and each `A` object has upto 100 `B` objects. So it will take a lot of time.

That means that there's a lot of work, but it doesn't necessarily mean your approach performs that work inefficiently. Is it spending time or memory on something that is unnecessary?

Maybe it is: Depending on how you update and save the individual `A` objects, `.prefetch_related('bs')` probably doesn't give you any advantage. The pre-fetched objects will definitely occupy memory space, and in your case a significant amount of it, due to their sheer number: There'll be up to **10 <sup>9</sup>** `B` objects. And you won't need those `B` objects' contents, just their count depending on content. But that can be computed by QuerySets like so:

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    bs = a.a_b
    a.count = (bs.filter(some_boolean=True).count() * 10
        + bs.filter(some_boolean=False).count())
    a.save()
```

Like this, the `B` table entries are never created as python objects for this code. The respective counts are computed by the underlying database, which should usually be significantly more efficient.

Even more efficient could be to let the database do the iterating over the `A` objects, too, and have it update them all in one go. [QuerySet's `update` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update) comes to mind, but in the documentation, I can't see how to use it to update the entries with entry-specific values, as we would need here. So I guess this isn't possible with django's ORM.

If you're willing to work around django's ORM, crafting an SQL `UPDATE` statement to that end with `sqlalchemy` or with something similar probably isn't too hard.

Comment: "Even more efficient could be to let the database do the iterating over the A objects, too, and have it update them all in one go." That is what i'm looking for. But this helps. I guess i can do this is the migration. Thanks man.